# Windows 7: Can I auto-start task manager?

Tags: windows-7, process-explorer, boot

Is there a way to automatically start up the task manager (in this case, process explorer) when I log into Windows 7?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right-click your desktop, go **New -> Shortcut**. Point the shortcut to the executable then drag it into the **startup** folder in the Start menu.

Comment: I've always done this, and then I change window to minimized in the shortcut's property to put it in the system tray directly.

Answer (score 3):

Use a login script to start taskmgr.exe or whatever executable you want. Or a scheduled task that is set to execute the chosen program upon system startup or user login.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Did this with previous versions of Windows but it didn't work first time I tried it in Vista.  Will try again in Win7.  Now can I make it automatically **restart** if it gets closed?  Or can I change the  close button so that it minimizes to the tray instead of getting closed?  Many programs do this but not TaskMan.

Thanks,